# Logging route changes in redux-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

Is it possible to log the current window location every time there's a route change when using `redux-router`?

I know this is possible in `react-router` using an onUpdate [handler](https://github.com/mozilla/react-ga/issues/31). ReduxRouter doesn't come with such a handler. Could I set up some middleware somehow in my store?

This is technically feasible by throwing a callback inside every ComponentWillUpdate but I'd like to just set everything up at the initialization of the router.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you got your answer on the github issue you created. For anyone also interested in this, take a look at this issue:

https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router/issues/240

Basically just set up a listener for the history. This solution is not depending on redux-router and can be used with everything using the history module for routing.